# When the degree of an ordinary differential equation is not defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please provide with some examples of ordinary differential equations that the degree is not defined?
For instance, $$(5y^4+3y^2+e^y)y'=\cos x\\ y^2=\ln(x+y')$$ The degree of the first is one; for the second is not defined. Am I right?

Comment: No, both are of degree $1.$ Please include to your post your definition of the degree of an ODE and why you think the second is not defined.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry! I corrected the question. Thanks

Comment: *Please* include to your post *your definition* of the degree of an ODE and why you think the second one (equivalent to $y'=e^{y^2}-x$) has no degree.

Comment: See many partly controversial discussions on this topic alone on this site: [search:](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bode%5D+order+degree+definition) "[ode] order degree definition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [this definition](https://byjus.com/maths/differential-equation-and-its-degree/) of the degree, then yes, $(5 y^4 + 3 y^2 + e^y) y' = \cos x$ has degree $1$ because it's polynomial in $y'$ of degree $1$ while  $y^2 = \ln(x+y')$ does not have a degree because the right side is not a polynomial in $y'$.  Of course it's equivalent to $\exp(y^2) = x + y'$ which has degree $1$.

Comment: OK try [this one](https://www.britannica.com/science/ordinary-differential-equation)